# R: Converting from Continuous 2D Points to Continuous 2D Vectors

Tags: r, vector, cartesian-coordinates

I have a fairly large dataframe (df) with pathing information in the form of continuous x,y coordinates:

df$x
df$y

With these data, I would like to:
1. Calculate a set of continuous vectors
2. Determine the angle between each of these vectors (in degrees)
3. Count the number of angles in the dataframe that meet a certain threshold (i.e. <90°)

Thank you!

[Please see the post here for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897704/angle-between-two-vectors-in-r)

Comment: Hi, this question is lacking a clear problem statement. You need to include what you've tried, and let us know why that isn't working, preferably with a reproducible example or specific error message.

Comment: My question lacks a clear problem statement? But yet, this obtuse question is acceptable and has 19 up-votes?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897704/angle-between-two-vectors-in-r

Comment: Yeah, I don't really like that one either. You're going to have to try and write your own code. Edit the question when you reach a specific problem.

Comment: What @economy is probably saying is that this problem is straightforward and you should have made some progress in its solution.  I've added one possible solution (without explanation) as an answer.

Comment: Thank you, sir... It's nice to see someone who is genuinely interested in helping out a fellow researcher. I am a behavioral ecologist studying the general search patterns of wolf spiders and I have a lot of tracking data to process. I am not a coder, although I am slowing becoming one out of necessity. I'll be sure you receive an acknowledgement when this paper published.

Answer (score 0):

```
require("ggplot2")

Hypocycloid <- function(num_points) {

  r = 1
  k = 3
  theta = seq(from = 0, to = 2*pi, length.out = num_points)

  x = r*(k - 1)*cos(theta) + r*cos((k - 1)*theta)
  y = r*(k - 1)*sin(theta) - r*sin((k - 1)*theta)

  df = data.frame(x = x, y = y)
  gg1 = ggplot(df,
               aes(x = x, y = y), 
               size = 1) +
        geom_path()
  print(gg1)

  return(df)
}

ComputeUnitVectors <- function(points_df) {
  npoints = nrow(points_df)
  vx = points_df$x[2:npoints] - points_df$x[1:(npoints-1)]
  vy = points_df$y[2:npoints] - points_df$y[1:(npoints-1)]
  length = sqrt(vx^2 + vy^2)
  return(data.frame(vx = vx/length, vy = vy/length))
}

ComputeAngles <- function(vectors_df) {

  Angle <- function(v1, v2) {
    return(acos(as.numeric(v1) %*% as.numeric(v2))*180/pi)
  }

  nvectors = nrow(vectors_df)
  v1 = vectors_df[1:(nvectors-1),]
  v2 = vectors_df[2:nvectors,]
  v_df = cbind(v1, v2)

  angle = apply(v_df, 1, function(row) {Angle(row[1:2], row[3:4])})
  return(data.frame(angle))
}

points.df = Hypocycloid(20)
vectors.df = ComputeUnitVectors(points.df)
print(vectors.df)
angles.df  = ComputeAngles(vectors.df)
print(angles.df)
```