# Angle between two vectors javascript

Tags: javascript, vector, 2d

I have a the a dotProduct function an a magnitude function. I am struggling to combine these to get the radians between of two vectors.

What I have so far is:

```
 Vector.prototype.angleBetween = function (secondVector) {
    var Vec1, Vec2, Vec3, Dot;
    Vec1 = this.magnitude();
    Vec2 = secondVector.magnitude();
    Vec3 = Vec1.getX() * Vec2.getX() + Vec1.getY() * Vec2.getY();
    Dot = Vec3 / Vec1 * Vec2;
    return new Math.cos(Dot);
};
```

I know I need to do the Dotproduct of the two vectors / magnitude of vec1 * vec2.

It must pass this jasmine test:

```
describe("Angle between", function () {
    var secondVector, angleBetween;
    secondVector = new Vector(-40, 30, 0);
    angleBetween = secondVector.angleBetween(vector);

    it("Result is PI/2", function () {
        expect(angleBetween).toBeCloseTo(Math.PI / 2, 1);
    });
});
```

Where am I going wrong on this?

Working Function:

```
Vector.prototype.angleBetween = function (secondVector) {
    var Vec1, Vec2, Vec3, Dot;


    Vec1 = this.magnitude();
    Vec2 = secondVector.magnitude();

    Vec3 = this.getX() * this.getY() + secondVector.getX() * secondVector.getY();

    Dot = this.dotProduct(this) * this.dotProduct(secondVector);

    return Math.acos(Vec3 / Vec1 * Vec2 * Math.PI / 2, 1);
};
```

Comment: To get an angle out you need an inverse trig function

Comment: Also you need parens on (vec1*vec2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return Math.acos (Vec3/(Vec1*Vec2))
Acos because you want the angle and parens to group the product of magnitudes. I Do not think new is needed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897704/angle-between-two-vectors-in-r/1898026 Gives the idea, but in R

Answer (score 0):

```
Vec1 = this.magnitude();
Vec2 = secondVector.magnitude();
Vec3 = Vec1.getX() * Vec2.getX() + Vec1.getY() * Vec2.getY();
```

isnt magnitude the lenght of the vector? you assign it to variables vec1 and vec2 and then call getX and getY as if they where Vectors.

Maybe you meant
Dot = this.getX() * secondVector.getX() + this.getY() * secondVector.getY();

and then

return acos(Dot/(Vec1*Vec2))

btw here are the functions
https://evanw.github.io/lightgl.js/docs/vector.html