# cross product doesn't give the correct sign in R

Tags: r, vector, angle

I have three vectors:

```
a0 <- c(0.5, 0.5)
a1 <- c(0.2, 0.75)
a2 <- c(0.75, 0.2)
```

I am trying to calculate the angle between `a0` and `a1` and between `a0` and `a2`. They should be the same in magnitude, but opposite in direction.

The correct way to do this is with cross product, but the way it is supposed to be implemented in R, namely `t(a0) %*% a1` does not capture this difference.

What is the correct way to do this in R? (there are analytical formulae for cross product, but what I actually want to do is generalize this to vectors in many dimensions)

Comment: I guess you have seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1897704/8881141) before asking this question?

Comment: Yes, I have. This discusses the dot product, which is much easier to do but is symmetric and doesnt give the sign of the angle

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2646573/24547