# Angle between vector and list of vectors in R

Tags: r, trigonometry

When comparing two vectors it is simple to calculate the angle between them, but in R it is noticeably harder to calculate the angle between a vector and a matrix of vectors efficiently.

Say you have a 2D vector A=(2, 0) and then a matrix B={(1,3), (-2,4), (-3,-3), (1,-4)}. I am interested in working out the smallest angle between A and the vectors in B. 
If I try to use

```
min(acos( sum(a%*%b) / ( sqrt(sum(a %*% a)) * sqrt(sum(b %*% b)) ) ))
```

it fails as they are non-conformable arguments.

Is there any code similar to that of above which can handle a vector and matrix?

Note: At the risk of being marked as a duplicate the solutions found in several [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897704/angle-between-two-vectors-in-r) do not apply in this case

Edit: The reason for this is I have a large matrix `X`, and `A` is just one row of this. I am reducing the number of elements based solely on the angle of each vector. The first element of `B` is the first in `X`, and then if the angle between any element in `B` and the next element `X[,2]` (here `A`) is greater than a certain tolerance, this is added to the list `B`. I am just using `B<-rbind(B,X[,2])` to do this, so this results in `B` being a matrix.

Comment: Is `B` meant to be a list or a matrix? A list I suppose.

Comment: Technically a list, but my R isn't very good so it has the type 'matrix'

Comment: As in `B=list(c(1,3), c(-2,4), c(-3,-3), c(1,-4))` ?

Comment: I have added an edit explaining how `B` is created which answers this

Comment: You should add a numeric example where you show the two inputs and the expected ouput, it will help with the answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't describe the format of A and B in detail, so I assume they are matrices by rows.

```
(A <- c(2, 0))
# [1] 2 0

(B <- rbind(c(1,3), c(-2,4), c(-3,-3), c(1,-4)))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]   -2    4
# [3,]   -3   -3
# [4,]    1   -4
```

---

**Solution 1** with `apply()`:

```
apply(B, 1, FUN = function(x){
  acos(sum(x*A) / (sqrt(sum(x*x)) * sqrt(sum(A*A))))
})

# [1] 1.249046 2.034444 2.356194 1.325818
```

**Solution 2** with `sweep()`: (replace `sum()` above with `rowSums()`)

```
sweep(B, 2, A, FUN = function(x, y){
  acos(rowSums(x*y) / (sqrt(rowSums(x*x)) * sqrt(rowSums(y*y))))
})

# [1] 1.249046 2.034444 2.356194 1.325818
```

**Solution 3** with `split()` and `mapply`:

```
mapply(function(x, y){
  acos(sum(x*y) / (sqrt(sum(x*x)) * sqrt(sum(y*y))))
}, split(B, row(B)), list(A))

#        1        2        3        4 
# 1.249046 2.034444 2.356194 1.325818
```

Answer (score 0):

The vector of dot products between the rows of `B` and the vector `A` is `B %*% A`.  The vector lengths of the rows of `B` are `sqrt(rowSums(B^2))`.

To find the smallest angle, you want the largest cosine, but you don't actually need to compute the angle, so the length of `A` doesn't matter.

Thus the row with the smallest angle will be given by `row <- which.max((B %*% A)/sqrt(rowSums(B^2)))`.  With Darren's data, that's row 1.

If you really do need the smallest angle, then you can apply the formula for two vectors to `B[row,]` and `A`.  If you need all of the angles, then the formula would be

```
acos((B %*% A)/sqrt(rowSums(B^2))/sqrt(sum(A^2)))
```